# Is there any infinite series representation of the sine integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions, indefinite-integrals

Is there any infinite series representation of the sine integral?

It is defined as $$\displaystyle \int\ \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\ dx$$

Comment: Like [these](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/SinIntegral/06/ShowAll.html)?

Comment: Sure. Expand $\sin$ in terms of a Taylor series. It converges uniformly and absolutely everywhere so you can exchange integral and sum.

Comment: See also http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.10#ii and http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int \frac{\sin{x}}{x}dx=\int\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}}{x}dx=\int\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k+1)!}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!\cdot (2k+1)}$$