# Infinite product representation for the Sine Integral $\mathrm{Si}(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions

The infinite series representation of the sine integral (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral, previous m.se question: [Is there any infinite series representation of the sine integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658005/is-there-any-infinite-series-representation-of-the-sine-integral)):
$$\operatorname{Si}(x)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)(2n+1)!}=x-\frac{x^3}{3!\cdot3}+\frac{x^5}{5!\cdot5}-\frac{x^7}{7! \cdot7}\pm\cdots$$

Is there a corresponding *infinite product representation*? I don't know how well the roots have been characterized, and sometimes digging through the literature for infinite product representations is tricky.

Comment: do you know Weierstrass factorisation Theorem? if so [see this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337861/weierstrass-factorization-of-sine-and-related-questions)